# Inline block auto fit to child width when child resize height

Tags: javascript, css, height, inline

I have slider populated with images in containers and every container has display inline-block.

Main slider has fixed width (for example 768px) and adjustable fixed height. I want child images and its containers fit in that height, and keep image proportions. When i change main slider height dynamically in developer tools or with Javascript, image container divs stay with same width and I have some empty space between every image in line (Images inside containers are scaled and keeps aspect ratio).

I try with:

```
.image{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

but problem persists.

Can I fix that only with CSS?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5wsp26pL/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to force the .image element to recalculate its size in any case i think that you have to use js

you can do this:

```
function reduceHeight() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.height = 200 + "px";
    $(".image").css('height', 200);
}
```

or:

JS

```
function reduceHeight() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.height = 200 + "px";
    $("container").addClass('reduced');
}
```

CSS

```
.reduced .image{
    height: 99%;
}
```

Anyway I hope you take the idea, just force it to change its size, changing properties like padding, border, works too.

I hope this helps